# How to get sub values inside JSON based on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have some dynamic JSON to populate a drop down box. How can I retrieve all the values inside the parameter section based on the user selection of the value.

For example if the user selects **report**, *startDate and endDate* values should be fetched

2nd example if the user changes the value to **report2**  I want to get the *programid, startDate  and endDate* values

```
<select class="form-control" id="reportName">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="report">Fees</option>
<option value="balances">Balances</option>
<option value="account"> Account Report</option>
<option value="report2"> Fee</option>
<option value="DI"> DI</option>
<option value="report3">Fees</option>
<option value="Rate_Report">Rate Report</option>
</select>
```

This code is used to populate the drop down box.

```
$.ajax({
    url: reports,
    dataType: "json",
    //jsonp:"jsoncallback",
     cache: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#reportName').empty();
        $('#reportName').append($('<option>').text("Select").attr('value', ''));    
        jQuery.each(data, function(k,v) {

               $('#reportName').append($('<option>').text(v.displayName).attr('value', v.name));
         });       
},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('FAILED to get  JSON from AJAX call' + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

    }
});
```

How can i get the values inside the various parameter(s)  using jquery ajax based on the user selection?

JSON

```
 [  
       {  
          "name":"report",
          "displayName":" Fees",
          "parameters":[  
             "startDate",
             "endDate"
          ],
          "formats":[  
             "EXCEL"
          ]
       },

       {  
          "name":"report2",
          "displayName":"Fee",
          "parameters":[  
             "programId",
             "startDate",
             "endDate"
          ],
          "formats":[  
             "EXCEL"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "name":"DI",
          "displayName":" DI",
          "parameters":[  
             "institutionId",
             "endDate"
          ],
          "formats":[  
             "EXCEL"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "name":"report3",
          "displayName":"Fees",
          "parameters":[  
             "startDate",
             "endDate",
             "programId"
          ],
          "formats":[  
             "EXCEL"
          ]
       },
       {  
          "name":"Rate_Report",
          "displayName":"Rate Report",
          "parameters":[  
             "balanceDate",
             "programId"
          ],
          "formats":[  
             "EXCEL"
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just that you need to add a data-param in each dynamically added element and add an onchange to get that whenever option value is changing. I hope this will be helpful :

**Your Mock Data :** https://api.myjson.com/bins/15p21r

**HTML :**

```
<select class="form-control" id="reportName">
</select>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15p21r",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $('#reportName').empty();
      $('#reportName').append($('<option>').text("Select").attr('value', ''));
      jQuery.each(data, function(k, v) {
        $('#reportName').append($('<option>').text(v.displayName).attr('value', v.name).attr('data-params', v.parameters));
      });
      $('#reportName').change(function(){
        selectedValue = $('#reportName option:selected').attr('data-params');
        alert(selectedValue);
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log('FAILED to get  JSON from AJAX call' + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

    }
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/v38bw9qv/

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the object from the json where the name property matches with the selected value.

So on change of `select` first get the selected value, then use the `array.filter` property to find the matched object.

From that object you can get the `parameters` key contains all the value you required

```
var json = [//.. json objects]

// on change get the selected value
$('#reportName').change(function() {
  /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  /* setting input box value to selected option value */
  // Use array filter to get filter out the object
  var getObject = json.filter(function(item) {
   return item.name == option
  });
  // the filtered array will have only one object. So picking 0 index
  // parameters is one of the key
  console.log(getObject[0].parameters)
});
```

Note: This is just to show how to retrieve the required values. You still need to make the ajax call to get the json

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/uzz7taLk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `data()` function. Bind json data to each select option using this `data()` method. And retrieve using this method only. `data()` function takes key and value pair  to set values use this

```
jQuery("#reportName").data("parameters",v.parameters)
```

To get values use

```
jQuery("#reportName").data("parameters")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sanjayarakeri/p7thv36u/